# whats wrong with my exported raster reclassify map in grass?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, reclassify

I'm trying to export a reclassify map in grass to a Geotiff format to pass it to DinamicaEgo platform.

I have 6 classes in grass but when I export it, the exported map show me 255 classes and they are numbered from 0 to 255. The classes 1 to 6 are my classification but the other not.

It's a problem when I load the raster to DinamicaEGO because it compare two classified images and make a probability matrix. So I only need the 6 classes not 255 classes.

Any one knows how can I make the exported raster only with the 6 classes?

I used the command r.reclass for reclassify the image and r.out.gdal for export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're just seeing the full color table that `r.out.gdal` creates by default. If you add the -c switch to avoid outputting a color table, you will get only the values you expect.

BTW, the answer by Jun Folledo might be misleading. There is nothing wrong with exporting a reclass raster directly to Geotiff. No need for recode.
Here's a simple example:

```
r.mapcalc -s "r = rand(1,100)"
r.reclass r output=r_reclass rules=- << EOF
> 1 thru 50 = 1
> 51 thru 100 = 2
> EOF
r.out.gdal -c r_reclass out=r_reclass.tif
```

Now I check the output Geotff with gdalinfo:

```
gdalinfo -stats r_reclass.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: r_reclass.tif
Size is 580, 580
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Transverse Mercator",
.....
Band 1 Block=580x14 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=2.000, Mean=1.505, StdDev=0.500
.....
    Generated_with=GRASS GIS 7.0.0
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1.5045749108205
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.49997906975291
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try r.recode

```
r.recode input=landcov_detailed output=landcov_reclassed << EOF
    1:3:1:1 forest
    4:7:2:2 grassland
    8:12:3:3 others
EOF
```

The above code reclassifies the original landcover map with 12 classes into 3 classes. Original classes 1 - 3 is classified into 1 and labeled as forest; orig. classes 4-7 are reclassified into 2 and labeled  as grassland; while classes 8-12 are reclassified to a new value of 3 and labeled as others.

Comment: This answer is misleading! The r.out.gdal function treats a reclass layer like a normal raster layer, i.e., your geotif file should have values 1 - 6. I would guess that Micha is right, and you are seeing the full colour table.

Comment: thanks, I'll edit my answer. I first used r.reclass but  I got more difficulty with it so now I use r.recode.